# counting the number of characters per line from a text file in C

Tags: c, count, line

so I am trying to count the number of characters in each line of the text file. I have successfully counted them but can't seem to get the last line of the text counted. here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000
#define NEWLINE '\n'

int 
main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    int bytes =-1, lines = 1;
    char x,line[MAXLINE];
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen("no.txt","r");
    printf("s0: query = \"%s\"\n",argv[1]);
    printf("---\n");

    if (file == NULL){
        printf("File doesn't exist \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while( fgets (line, 1000, file)!=NULL ) 
    {
        printf("%s",line); 

        while((x = getchar())!= EOF ){
            bytes +=1;
            if (x == NEWLINE){
                printf("S1: line %6d, bytes = %3d\n---\n",lines,bytes);
                bytes = -1;
                break;
            }
        }
        lines +=1;
    } 

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loop:

```
while((x = getchar())!= EOF ){
```

Is reading from the console instead of from the file.  That's probably not what you want.  You've already read in a line from the file using `fgets`, so you just need to use `strlen` to see how long it is.  However, since `fgets` leaves the newline in the buffer, you'll need to remove it first by putting a NULL byte in place of the newline.

So your main loop should look like this:

```
while( fgets (line, 1000, file)!=NULL ) 
{
    line[strlen(line)-1] = 0;   // remove newline
    printf("%s\n",line);   // print a newline, since the line no longer contains one
    printf("S1: line %6d, bytes = %3d\n---\n",lines,strlen(line));
    lines +=1;
}
```